# Why does the previous entry in a file get erased once the func is called again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help and am a beginner programmer, how are we meant to make sure that the previous function calls values are first saved to the txt and that the next time the function is called it writes on the next line?

```
def add_employee(name, id, date_joined, job):
    with open('employees.txt', 'w+') as txtfile:
        line = 'ID: {0} --- Name: {1} --- Date_Joined: {2} --- Job: {3}'.format(id, name, date_joined, job)
        txtfile.write(line)
    txtfile.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: No need for `txtfile.close()`, the `with` statement will close it automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to open the file with "a" instead if "w+" for appending to the file.

Comment: Thanks but it now writes all the entries next to each other on one line, any way to make sure its on the next line?

Comment: @Amen: You can add a newline at the end of each line.

Comment: with '/n' it doesnt work

Comment: It's `\n`, with a backslash.